# java add new line to txt\log file

Tags: java, file, text, newline

I'm trying to create a log file to my java script that will save the time when the unit is up.

it's working - every boot he save me the time in the file 
but I want to add a new line every boot , and now it overwrite the file 
so the file is allways 1 line (the last time it boot)

what do I need to change?

this is the code I have wrote :

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
    {

        Writer output; //to write the data into a file 
        String PathOfFile = "/home/pi/boot.log";
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(PathOfFile);
        output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(PathOfFile , true));
        Calendar Time = Calendar.getInstance(); //get the time 
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy-HH:mm:ss");

        try 
        {
            System.out.println("Hello - the device is UP and running now :-)");

            output.append ("\r\n" + sdf.format(Time.getTime()) + "   Unit is UP\r\n " );
            output.close();

            System.exit(0);
        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.err.println(e);
            output.append (sdf.format(Time.getTime()) +  "    " + e );
            output.close();

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: It's working for me as intended. Are you sure your file is not get deleted with every new boot?

Comment: no , this is the fulll code  , and this is the only place in the I'm using this file.

Comment: can you provide sample output

Comment: 11/06/2018-13:34:25   Unit is UP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PrintWriter's method is called append() doesn't mean that it changes the mode of the file being opened.

You need to open the file in append mode as well:

Also, you are not using printwriter in your code, so this can be removed.
Try this

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
    {

        Writer output; //to write the data into a file 
        String PathOfFile = "/home/pi/boot.log";
        //PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(PathOfFile , true /* append = true */)
        output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(PathOfFile , true));
        Calendar Time = Calendar.getInstance(); //get the time 
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy-HH:mm:ss");
        try 
        {
            System.out.println("Hello - the device is UP and running now :-)");
            output.append ("\r\n" + sdf.format(Time.getTime()) + "   Unit is UP\r\n " );
            output.close();

            System.exit(0);
        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.err.println(e);
            output.append (sdf.format(Time.getTime()) +  "    " + e );
            output.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are opening file with `PrintWriter` instance as well, not in append mode, which removes the content and after that you are writing with `Writer` (`output`) to the file.

**Solution:**

Just remove the `PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(PathOfFile);`, you are not using it anyway in your code.

Comment: I didn't realize this, as my IDE removed unused statements, so it has worked for me before...

Comment: Thanks , I used this for something else and forgot about it .........  Thank you!!

Comment: No problem :). Please marked this as an answer, in case it has solved your problem.